# Restatement of definitions of pointwise/uniform convergences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the definition of pointwise convergence: sequence $f_{n}$ converges pointwise on A to f

$$\forall x\in A\;\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists N:\; n\geq N\Rightarrow|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)|<\epsilon$$

The part after “$\forall x\in A$” coincides with a description of limit of sequence, hence we can rewrite the definition of pointwise convergence as

$$\forall x\in A\;\lim f_{n}\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$$

My question is how to rewrite the definition of uniform convergence in the same way?

$$\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists N:\; n\geq N,\; x\in A\Rightarrow|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sometimes re-states uniform convergence in the equivalent form:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in A}\left\vert f(x)-f_n(x)\right\vert\right)=0$$

Indeed, $\ \sup_{x\in A}\left\vert f(x)-f_n(x)\right\vert\le\varepsilon\Longleftrightarrow \forall x\in A,\, |f(x)-f_n(x)|\le\varepsilon$ and you can plug this into the definition of limit.